# No funciona CSS: no se aplica en HTML

Tags: html, css

Estoy aprendiendo desarrollo web y tuve problemas para vincular el archivo css en mi html. He construido el servidor web con node y express, la estructura del proyecto es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado de diferentes formas ingresar la ruta al archivo css y no he obtenido resultados. El código es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán, no se aplican los estilos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funciona solamente agregando la etiqueta `<style>` dentro del html, pero mi intención es tener los archivos separados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal? ¿Mi computadora puede estar mal configurada?

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes para mostrar código, copia y pega el texto

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con la [documentación](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) debes definir un directorio para el contenido estático usando la función `express.static`. Por ejemplo usando el directorio `public` con la siguiente estructura:

```bash
app.js
src/
public/
   styles/
      styles.css
```

en el archivo `app.js` defines el directorio público

```javascript
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

luego el link debería ser como el siguiente

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css" />
```